# Android- interface in fragment will instantiate in onAttach() but not otherwise

Tags: android, interface, android-fragments, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I have created an interface inside a fragment, and implemented it in the parent activity.

When the code looks like this, everything works perfectly:

```
public class ExercisesCatsFragment extends Fragment {
OnCategorySelected mCallback;
...
    @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    mCallback = (OnCategorySelected) activity;
}
```

But when I try to instantiate mCallback in the class itself, I get a nullpointerexception when the interface is called. The non working code looks like this (with no overridden onAttach()):

```
public class ExercisesCatsFragment extends Fragment {
OnCategorySelected mCallback = (OnCategorySelected) this.getActivity();
```

Does anyone know the reason behind it? The parent activity is a FragmentActivity; could this be the fault?

Thank you

Comment: You are calling `this.getActivity()` in the main body of the `Fragment` - at that point it isn't attached to an `Activity`. Just do it the way you show in the first code block.

Comment: You're right. It slipped my mind completely. Please submit this as an answer so that I can rate/accept it :)

Comment: I've converted my comment to an answer. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the second (non-working) code you are calling `this.getActivity()` in the main body of the Fragment - at that point it isn't attached to an `Activity` so `this.getActivity()` will return `null`.

Just do it the way you show in the first code block or alternatively in the `onCreate(...)` method of the `Fragment`.